# Need jQuery UI Dialog to update dropdown values

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I got this jQuery UI on their website, and I wanted to remake it for a simple college calculation app. My plan was to take out the basic data like email, username, and so on and replace it with 3 main dropdown menus. 1 to see if they are an in-state or out-of state student, which both will have different values. Another dropdown will ask if they are staying on college and depending on their input it'll update the cost, then the last dropdown menu will ask how many years they will be attending. Based on the 3 inputs, it calculate the total cost of that college. What i need is it to post the values of the dropdown menus instead of the textboxes. Thanks for any help!!
So I currently have this:

style:

```
<style>
body { font-size: 62.5%; }
label, input { display:block; }
input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee;
padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
.validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
</style>
```

jQuery script

```
<script>
$(function() {
var username = $( "#username" ),
  studenttut = $( "#studenttut" ),
  studenttut = $( "#campusrb" ),
  studenttut = $( "#yearsatten" ),
  allFields = $( [] ).add( username ).add( studenttut ).add( campusrb ).add( yearsatten ),
  tips = $( ".validateTips" );

function updateTips( t ) {
  tips
    .text( t )
    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
  setTimeout(function() {
    tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
  }, 500 );
}

function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
  if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
    updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
      min + " and " + max + "." );
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
  if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
    updateTips( n );
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create an account": function() {
      var bValid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      bValid = bValid && checkLength( username, "username", 3, 16 );
      bValid = bValid && checkLength( studenttut, "studenttut", 1, 2 );
      bValid = bValid && checkLength( campusrb, "campusrb", 1, 2 );
      bValid = bValid && checkLength( yearsatten, "yearsatten", 1, 2 );       
      bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( username, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may           consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
      bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( studenttut, /^[1-2]/, "Please select an option for the type of student you'll be." );
      bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( campusrb, /^[1-2]/, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
      bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( yearsatten, /^[1-8]/, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );

      if ( bValid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + username.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + studenttut.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + campusrb.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + yearsatten.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});

$( "#create-user" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
<label for="username">username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text ui-widget-content ui-    corner-all" />


<label for="studenttut">Are you a In-state/Out-of-state student?</label>
<select name="studenttut" id="studenttut" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />
    <option value="1">In-State-student</option>
    <option value="2">Out-of-State-student</option> 
</select>

<label for="campusrb">Are you staying on campus?</label>
    <select name="campusrb" id="campusrb" class="text ui-widget-content ui- corner-all" />
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select an option</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="2">No</option> 
    </select>

<label for="yearsatten">How many years are you planning to attend??</label>
    <select name="yearsatten" id="yearsatten" class="text ui-widget-content ui-  corner-all" />
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please   select an option</option>     
        <option value="1">1 year</option> 
        <option value="2">2 years</option> 
        <option value="3">3 years</option>
        <option value="4">4 years</option>
        <option value="5">5 years</option>
        <option value="6">6 years</option>
        <option value="7">7 years</option>
        <option value="8">8 years</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Total Cost</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>

</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What do you want to change in it? Sorry, I don't get it..

Comment: When i submit, it doesnt submit the radiobutton data only text data. I need the script to pass the values to update my page.

Comment: use this as a reference, I want it like this but instead of the checkboxes being submitted, I want radiobuttons being submitted. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + username.val() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $('#studenttut>option:selected').text() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $('#campusrb>option:selected').text() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $('#yearsatten>option:selected').text() + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" );
```